hide input tag whose placeholder is "Max contacts added"
I have a single select PeoplePicker that shows a disabled input tag with a placeholder "Max contacts added".
How should I select it with CSS to set disply:none on it?
the dev tool shows:
<input 
  class="control" 
  part="control" 
  id="control" 
  placeholder="Max contacts added" 
  type="text" 
  aria-atomic="true" 
  aria-label="Maximum contact selections reached" 
  aria-live="assertive" 
  disabled="true"
>

I tried
#control {
    display: none;
}

and
.control {
    display: none;
}

But it is still there
Thank you

Both must work. Did you inspect the element to see it the styles are applied? Something is overriding those styles IMO (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

This control also might be under the shadowDOM, which prevents your styles from applying. So more details needed, maybe link to an example.

Use an attribute selector with the placeholder text.
input[placeholder="Max contacts added"]



input[placeholder="Max contacts added"] {
  background: lightblue;
}
<input class="control" part="control" id="control" placeholder="Max contacts added" type="text" aria-atomic="true" aria-label="Maximum contact selections reached" aria-live="assertive" disabled="true">



